# position:fixed is not working in the second part of div in react JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have one **parent div** which has **two children div**,vertically divided the screen in to two equal halves. I have given **position:fixed** to the second children div to make it non scrollable but it came out of its actual position. Can any one please enlighten me on how to make second children div non scrollable by keeping in its original position.

Edited:     `Please check the code`  https://jsfiddle.net/stackoverflow748/9n0kpv84/91/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should post your code, at least enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pointy. I have edited my question.

Comment: Your code doesn't have position: fixed 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the first child `div` to be scrollable and the second one to be fixed, right? You could try these styles for the second child `div`:

```
.child2 {
  width:50%;
  background-color:blue;
  position:fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sultan Singh Atwal. That's working perfect.

Comment: You're welcome @StackOverflowAsker! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://codepen.io/raibove/pen/ZELMQGG) what you want to do? The second div is sticked to bottom and is not scrollable.

For second div:

```
position:fixed; 
bottom:0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Shweta. Sorry, my bad. I have updated my question. I have two child divs vertically aligned. Please check my js fiddle link.